# Is it correct to use Wilcoxon signed rank test on mean data?

Tags: mean, dataset, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have X individuals and 2 category of interest (category A and category B) per individual. The problem is that is have a variability in the number of measures I have between individuals and between categories. I thus decided to compute a mean, so I get something like that:

Individual 1:
category A: 2.34 (mean of 4 measures),
category B: 4.56 (mean of 10 measures).

Individual 2:
category A: 6.78 (mean of 12 measures),
category B: 1.23 (mean of 6 measures).

And so on.

I want to compare category A and category B. Is it correct to use Wilcoxon signed rank test in this case? I wonder because the data on which I will use it is mean data.

Thank you for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct, it might be good enough if there is a larger number if measurements per each subject or if the difference is not too large, but strictly speaking each of your means are measured at different precision and the test does not take that into account.

Better way would be to use a test where contribution of each subjects is weighted be the number of measurements or a random effect it a multi level model.

These approaches are usually parametric and i don't know if there is some version of the Wilcoxon test that can take different percussion's into account. If you need something non-parametric then a permutation test will be able to do this, but the permutation scheme might be a bit complex and you might need to code it yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That does help. You wrote that "Better way would be to use a test where contribution of each subjects is weighted be the number of measurements or a random effect it a multi level model." Could you tell me a bit more about this, or give me the name of the first test you're referring to? Even if these are parametric. Thanks again