# Correct approach for paired Wilcoxon test

Tags: mean, median, likert, paired-data

I have a 5 Likert Scale rating for 30 stories and for 30 altered versions of those stories. I want to compare these, so I want to do a paired Wilcoxon test.

My problem: I now have a different number of ratings for each story, ie.

Story 1 - > 3 ratings // Modified Story 1 - > 2 ratings

Story 2 - > 7 Ratings // Modified Story 2 - > 8 Ratings

Story 3 - > 5 Ratings // Modified Story 3 - > 4 Ratings

....

Story 30 -> 6 Ratings // Modified Story 30 - > 5 Ratings

My solution, I first take the Mean/Median for all stories and then run the Paired Wilcoxon Test. Is this still serious? Or is there a better approach for this?

I don't want to mix all stories together (Mann-Whitney U test), because they have a connection. Or am I making a mistake in my thinking here?

Thank you very much!
Tom

Comment: A few comments...  a) By "scale", do you mean a single Likert-type question or the results of several question combined ?  b) It's not best to use the means or medians and treat them as a single observation.  Perhaps see this recent question: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590320/is-it-correct-to-use-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-on-mean-data).

Comment: Thanks! a) I have multiple items that form a construct. b) ok, so i need a non-parametric  permutation test for the whole construct..?